# Zipping files in a folder MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, zip, directory

A folder named *Test_UL* contains files like *Test_file_UL.exe*, *Test_file_UL.iso* and *Test_file_UL.txt*.

I need to zip the *Test_file_UL.exe* and *Test_file_UL.iso* files to *Test.zip*, excluding *Test_file_UL.txt*.

How can I do this using MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an ItemGroup for the items you want, and then passing that item group to a powershell cmdlet.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ZipFiles Include="Test_UL\Test_file_UL.exe" />
  <ZipFiles Include="Test_UL\Test_file_UL.iso" />
</ItemGroup>
```

All the usual rules for [item groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemgroup-element-msbuild) apply, so you can do whatever filtering you need.

Then invoke powershell to zip the files:

```
<Target Name="CreateZip">
    <Exec Command="PowerShell -NoProfile -Command Compress-Archive @(ZipFiles->'%(Identity)', ',') -DestinationPath $(ZipName)" />
</Target>
```

- [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1) is a powershell cmdlet available in PowerShell
  5 onwards.
- @(ZipFiles->'%(Identity)', ',') is an [MSBuild Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-transforms),
  changing the files into a comma separated list.

There are also MSBuild extensions that add a zip/compress target, but I've always found it easier to just quickly call powershell.